# Is there any way to control system cursor ( send double click signal to system )

Tags: java

I have seen an application named camera mouse which enables movement of cursor with the help of head. That is when head is moved cursor is moved .I am looking for any functions in java which can move the cursor , send double click signal to the system .( any reference, source code or links )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class from AWT.

Comment: This link is no longer working, can you provide any type of update?

Answer (score 1):

<del>See this [demo](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.awt/MoveMouse.html) of Robot class.</del>

Take a look at [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class. Here is a simple example of [mouseMove](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#mouseMove%28int,%20int%29):

```
public void moveCursor(int x, int y) {
    try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.mouseMove(x, y);
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```